# What happens when a genome is shorter than the other?

Tags: genetics, dna, mutations, genomes

Say there were 2 creatures of the same species. Creature 1 has a longer genome than creature 2, it may be just a few base pairs, but what would happen when the genes were crossed to create creature 3 (via Sexual Reproduction)? Do the genes know where to match up or are there genes that end up being corrupted during this process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there wont be a third species when you cross two organims of the same species with one which has a mutation in some areas of its genome. All of us have some mutation or the other and our genomes are never identical. So when humans have kids, you can expect some mutations in the child but never another species. Unless you are talking about evolution over millions of years or a case where there is crossbreeding between species like a horse and a donkey

Comment: @TheLastWord a second or third species was never mentioned. OP talks about *Creatures* 1, 2, and 3, but they are all the same species. The question seems pretty clear to me - *What happens when homologous sequences of DNA have short insertions or deletions on one chromosome but not the other?*

Comment: What type of "matching up" and possible "corruption" (during recombination?) are you referring to? Mitosis in creature 3, meiosis in creature 3 or normal gene expression during the life of creature 3?